# Redis python client connections increased under heavy load

Tags: python, redis

My app adopt redis as cache and redis-py as client to access it. In one special request will invoke 65 redis visits, including LRANGE, GET, LLEN.

Under test of 4 req/s, the command `redis-cli client list | wc -l` always shows 3 connections during the test running. But when the concurrent req increased to 50 req/s, there will show redis client connections count increased as the test runing. For a 3 minutes duration, the connections will increased to 1000+. As a result, the performance of my app is decreased drastically.

So what may be the reason for the problem? Any suggestion is appreciated.

The result of redis-benchmark -n 100000 -q is

```
PING_INLINE: 73637.70 requests per second
PING_BULK: 75414.78 requests per second
SET: 75301.21 requests per second
GET: 75528.70 requests per second
INCR: 75930.14 requests per second
LPUSH: 76103.50 requests per second
LPOP: 74074.07 requests per second
SADD: 75301.21 requests per second
SPOP: 74794.31 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 75301.21 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 38182.51 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 15128.59 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 11152.00 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 8797.40 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 42936.88 requests per second
```

The app and redis are running in the same virtual host, and base environment is E5-2620 * 2 CPU, 4G Mem.

Comment: 1000 concurrent connections are not a problem for redis, you might be hitting some kernel connection limit (eg. ubuntu limits to 1024 by default)

Comment: I have changed the kernel limit of file-max to 128000, and the connections has been reached to 1800+, so I'm afraid something else should be the reason.

Comment: then it means you are spawning too many connections or leaking them in your application code, what library are you using to connect to redis ?